# Angular HTTPS deployment

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, https

I have an Angular application which is using HTTP API (not HTTPS). I would like to deploy the Angular application on HTTPS (on IIS) however it throws an error while calling the HTTP API.

Is there anyway I can deploy the Angular application on HTTPS and still use HTTP api?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Possible to allow HTTP requests from HTTPS website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29850867/possible-to-allow-http-requests-from-https-website)